# Postgress function not working as expected with LOOP and INTO

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have following procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createtestdata(
    )
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
        proj RECORD;
        ruleid integer;
        emailtemplateid integer;
        otherTemplates RECORD;
        markdoenTemplateId integer;
        pdfTemplateId integer;
        jsonTemplateId integer;
    BEGIN
    

        FOR proj IN
            SELECT p.id AS project_id FROM project p
            WHERE p.id != 10409 and p.projecttype='software'
            ORDER BY p.id
        LOOP
            select  "ID" from "TEST_TEMPLATES" 
            where "PROJECT_ID" = proj.project_id AND "TYPE" =1 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
            INTO emailtemplateid;
            RAISE NOTICE 'template id is %...', emailtemplateid;

            select  "ID", "TYPE" from "TEST_TEMPLATES" 
            where "PROJECT_ID" = proj.project_id AND "TYPE" IN (2,4,5)
            ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
            INTO otherTemplates;

            RAISE NOTICE 'OTHER TEMPLATES %',   otherTemplates; 
            RAISE NOTICE 'inserting records for project id %...', proj.project_id;

            pdfTemplateId = NULL;
            markdoenTemplateId = NULL;
            jsonTemplateId = NULL;

            IF otherTemplates."TYPE" = 2 THEN
                pdfTemplateId = otherTemplates."ID";
            ELSIF otherTemplates."TYPE" = 4 THEN
                markdoenTemplateId = otherTemplates."ID";
            ELSIF otherTemplates."TYPE" = 5 THEN
                jsonTemplateId = otherTemplates."ID";
            END IF;
            RAISE NOTICE 'PDF TEMP IS %... MKDN TEMP IS %... JSON TEMP IS %', 
            pdfTemplateId, markdoenTemplateId, jsonTemplateId;  

            INSERT INTO "TEST_RULES"(
                "BEFORE_NOF_DAYS", "CREATED", "CREATED_BY", "CRON_EXPRESSION", "IS_ACTIVE", 
                "IS_DELETED", "MODIFIED", "MODIFIED_BY", "NAME", 
                "PROJECT_ID", "SCHEDULE_TIME", "TRIGGER_TYPE", "VERSION_PATTERN")
            VALUES (null, now(), 'admin', null, true, 
                    false, now(), 'admin', 'rule for release project ' || proj.project_id, 
                    proj.project_id, null, 2, null) 
            RETURNING "ID" INTO ruleId;

            RAISE NOTICE 'Inserting email action for Rule id just created is %...', ruleId;


            
            INSERT INTO "TEST_RULE_ACTIONS"(
                "ACTION_TYPE", "CONFLUENCE_INSTANCE_ID", "CREATED", "CREATED_BY", "EMAIL_FROM", 
                "EXTERNAL_USERS", "IS_DELETED", "JIRA_GROUPS", "JIRA_USERS", "JSON_TEMPLATE_ID", "MARKDOWN_TEMPLATE_ID",
                "MODIFIED", "MODIFIED_BY", "NAME", 
                "PAGE_LABEL", "PARENT_ID", "PDF_TEMPLATE_ID", "PORTAL_ID", "POST_END_POINT", "POST_PASSWORD", 
                "POST_TEMPLATE_TYPE", "POST_TYPE", "POST_USER_NAME", "REPLY_TO", "RULE_ID", 
                "SEND_EMAIL_AS_BCC", "SEQUENCE_NUMBER", "SPACE_KEY", "TEMPLATE_ID", "TEMPLATE_TYPE_ID")
            VALUES (1, NULL, NOW(), 'admin', 'stest@test.com', 
                '', false, 'arn-users', 'admin', jsonTemplateId, markdoenTemplateId, 
                now(), 'admin', 'email action configured for project ' || proj.project_id, 
                NULL, 0, pdfTemplateId, 0, NULL, NULL, 
                NULL, 'page', NULL, 'stest@test.com', ruleId, 
                    false, 1, NULL, emailtemplateid, 1);

        END LOOP;

        RETURN true;
    END;
$BODY$;
```

When I run the function, I get output

```
psql:dproc.sql:122: NOTICE:  template id is 3425...
psql:dproc.sql:122: NOTICE:  project id 10494...
psql:dproc.sql:122: NOTICE:  OTHER TEMPLATES (1709,5)
psql:dproc.sql:122: NOTICE:  PDF TEMP IS <NULL>... MKDN TEMP IS <NULL>... JSON TEMP IS 1709
psql:dproc.sql:122: NOTICE:  inserting records for project id 10497...
**psql:dproc.sql:122: NOTICE:  Inserting email action for Rule id just created is <NULL>...**
```

The last line "Inserting email action for Rule id just created is " is wrong, the insert statement works correctly on my local SQL. but this does not work on AWS postgres

Also if I put the insert statement at first statement in loop, it works. but then other two statements do not work

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted is the code that is running?  Your `NOTICE` lines for `PDF TEMP IS. . .` and `inserting records for project id. . .` are out of order in your output.

Comment: What are the two statements that don't work when you move the `INSERT` to the top?

Comment: When you say is works locally but not on AWS, do you mean the entire function or the just the `INSERT`? Also how does that relate to moving the `INSERT` in the function?

Comment: problem was with ruleid integer; the one used INTO statement is ruleId. This function worked on local windows postgres, but failed on AWS rds postgresql. I corrected the case of variable and it worked